# Could we introduce the lang attribute?

Tags: feature-request, localization

When I create a question or add a comment on StackExchange sites all text within the textarea gets a red underline because of spellchecking - I use a german brower localization (Firefox). AFAIK if those textareas get a `lang` attribute set to 'en' this would be easily fixed. I think this is also an improvement in regards to applying HTML standards. For non-English StackExchange sites `lang` could be set to another value.

Another option that I don't prefer would be to use spellcheck="false".

Or the lang attribute could be set to whole page.

Some references:

- https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-language-declarations.en
- https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-lang-why.en
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/lang

I don't know whether this can be seen as a feature-request or as a bug.